# Hide facebook banner from getting displayed in browser

Tags: browser, webpage

While visiting a website (Times of India in  this case), on sides of the article the Facebook banner is getting displayed. This banner hides most of the text in the article and hovers over the article text as I scroll down the webpage.

As I am currently accessing the website from office, almost all social networking  sites are blocked. 
Below is an image while visiting an article from http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-uJrvyyXrOBaDc2U3dzMlN1Tnc/edit?usp=sharing

Is there a way to hide/disable this banner from getting displayed in the browser?

Comment: Try installing [Disconnect](https://disconnect.me/). That may help.

Comment: image in the question is no longer available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?hl=en

This extension will hide all of the ads, not only Facebook banners.

Add Ghostery to the mix:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ghostery/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij?hl=en

Works for me.

On the other hand your proxy is not really well configured. I actually suspect no proxy but firewall rules in place.

Comment: I have Adblock Plus installed (so not exactly the Adblock you linked) and I see the Facebook popup in question.

Comment: Works for me: FF: http://i.imgur.com/CGwFWWC.png CHROME: http://i.imgur.com/kqhvqys.png

Comment: But did you click the x button? If you click the x button even once, India Times apparently stops displaying the popup server-side, regardless of cookies or if you use a different browser. In other words, maybe you clicked the x button once and now you think that it's Adblock that is blocking the popup. Also, Chris, did you downvote my answer?

Comment: @nitro2k01 there is no x botton :/

Comment: @Ankit That comment was for Chris.

Comment: @Chris I opened that link again just to check, and yet it was there.

Comment: @Ankit Did you actually install the extensions in those links? And it didn't work?

Comment: @nitro2k01 No - I did not click any "x" as that ad wasn't there. This is the first time I've been to this site. Ankit: install those extensions, clear cache and try again. Works for me!

Comment: @Chris Nevertheless, I give you the same challenge as in the comments to my answer. Show that you can make the popup appear by disabling Adblock or whatever extensions you have installed. Otherwise it may be a false positive. (Maybe the site wouldn't have shown the popup to you anyway for some reason, for example.) Impulsive downvoters, gotta hate'em.

Answer (score 1):

A way to disable Facebook banners is using the uBlock Origin Add-On to Firefox. You can add a custom filter, reading e.g.

```
! Remove Facebook Log In / Sign Up banner 
facebook.com###pagelet_growth_expanding_cta
```

(uBlock-Origin Preferences -> My Filters).

I found a more detailed description/instruction here (filter rule was copy pasted from this reference): 
http://www.block011.de/2016/09/21/how-to-block-the-log-in-sign-up-popup-on-facebook/

Answer (score 0):

No computer wizard here, but having the same problem I started messing around with Firefox. What I found that removed the banner was this. First click "not now" on banner. Then right click on the FB sign up login in banner and select "inspect element". Then roll over HTML till the banner highlights in blue. Then right click on that HTML and select "delete node". You will be deleting something like this........

Comment: .....<div class="_4-u2 _5hnd _4-u8" id="u_0_62" style="display: block;".......Then close the inspect element box by clicking on X in top right corner.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>it seems that the `www.facebook.com###u_0_3` filter in uBlock Origin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm works very well.</strike>

The facebook dynamic div naming disables using `u_0_3` for easy filtering. On one page it's logon enforcement div, on the other page is it some other structural element and you can't see the whole page without it.

The https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/21545-facebook-disable-facebook-force-register-box/code works well, you can plug it into Chrome's Tampermonkey https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo or Firefox Greasemonkey https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/.

Answer (score -2):

There's normally an X button to close this popup. Clicking this button sets a cookie. You could try simulate pressing the button by setting this cookie manually. You can for example do this using Javascript. In a tab where you have India Times open, summon your browser's developer tools and copy/paste the following code into the Javascript console, and then press enter. Then reload the page and see if it worked. You can access the developer tools by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (Firefox) or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (Chrome) or <kbd>F12</kbd> (Internet Explorer) .

```
document.cookie ='disableautolg=1; expires=Thu, 2 Aug 2015 20:47:11 UTC; path=/';
```

Comment: This will not work for most of the ads and that would have to be done manually every time there is an pop-up.

Comment: @Chris if you read the question and looked at the asker's screenshot, you'll see that he's not asking about ads in general, but a specific problem. Facebook is blocked at his work, which means that the India Times page is covered by a Facebook popup asking him to like the page. This is arguably not an ad.

Comment: @nitro2k01 As FB is blocked the close button will not be shown in the ad view. There will be no option to close. So I think the best solution is to use ADBlock plus.

Comment: @gladiator2345 As described in my comment to Chris' answer, I don't think Adblock is actually blocking the popup in question (actually a div shown on the page.) Therefore, I don't believe that advice is useful. Once you've clicked the X, the server doesn't present you with the popup again for connections from the same IP, and you may erroneously think that Adblock is blocking it. A challenge for you and Chris to prove that Adblock is the thing blocking it: Make the popup return by disabling Adblock, clearing cookies or whatever you have to do.